# EmailJS REST API with React Hook Forms

Tags: reactjs, api, axios, react-hook-form

I'm currently using React Hook Forms and attempting to use the EmailJS API request to send the email.
I am sure the environment variables are being passed in correctly, as I've console logged and checked the three keys provided by EmailJS to send the request successfully.
I'm wondering if my formatting of the request is wrong? I'm always getting error 400 (which by EmailJS documentation, that I'm not correctly putting in the user_id key).

Below is the submit function that is called when the form is submitted.
The EmailJS documentation insists that the parameters of the keys are passed in as such and the data is passed in under "template_params"

```
const onSubmit = (data: IContactForm) => {


    const emailData = {
      service_id: serviceID,
      template_id: templateID,
      user_id: userID,
      template_params: JSON.stringify(data)
    };


    axios({
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'https://api.emailjs.com/api/v1.0/email/send',
      data: emailData
    })

  };
```

Thank you for your time. Greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution to this?